# Getting "PlatformNotSupportedException" in .NETCore 3.1 and 4.7 System.IO.Ports

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, serial-port

I am working on multiplatform library which uses System.IO.Ports.

Library is written in .NET Core 3.1 and uses System.IO.Ports 4.7 from Nuget, apperently this version should already be avaiable with linux thos linux is supported. But stiull when I run the main application, it causes the same problem

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.IO.Ports is currently only supported on Windows.
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits)
```

When I was googling this problem, I found that combination of System.IO.Ports 4.7 and .NET Core 3.1 should work on linux, but nothing.

P.S. I also tried different libraries like `crozone.SerialPorts`, but every single library has some issue which is not working, f.e. `invlaid parameter when running /dev/stty` etc... **Is there some library which solves this problem, linux/windows usage of Serial Ports?**

Thank you very much

Comment: I solve my problem with earlier mentioned library crozone.SerialPorts. I recommend this library, is working like a charm and its actually quite eeasy to setup for Windows and Linux both.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install package of System.IO.Ports (not dll file Only) that include:

-Microsoft.win32.Registry ...

-System.Memory

-runtime.native.System.IO.ports ...

-System.ioPorts.dll

You can install it with Package manager Console if version of package you want to use  is higher than exists in VS nuget .

This method has worked for me